# Couldn't communicate with a helper application when i pick the zip file from the iCloud using UIDocumentPickerViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud, simulator, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

Whenever i pick the file from the iCloud using UIDocumentPickerviewcontroller from my application but it will show this alert on `iPhone` simulator.

[image]

```
NSArray *types = @[(NSString*)kUTTypeArchive];
UIDocumentPickerViewController *docPicker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:types inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
docPicker.delegate = self;
docPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
[self presentViewController:docPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I have same problem but i change Change kUTTypeArchive to kUTTypeItem, you can try it.

Comment: ya sure but i need only zip file.

Comment: Ok fine, you can find all type on 


https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1

Search on this page .zip and you find out many solution, i hope it's help you

Comment: Actually the problem is whenever i picked the zip file from the iCloud. it will show the above alert on iPhone simulator that is my problem. My problem is not in the UTType

Comment: I try same code but i didn't get any alert, did you tried in device?

Comment: Ok i will try in my device. but i need to know why this alert message show in iPhone simulator.

Comment: Can i ask what is your simulator and xCode version???

Comment: it is perfectly works on device. Xcode 11.2.1 and Mac os version 10.14.6 Mojave and iPhone xr simulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's problem in only new `Xcode 11.2.1` Simulator OS 13.2.

Because I also try in `Xcode 10.2` and XS Max, It's work properly.

In all Device work properly so don't worry about this alert.

**Hope it will be solve by Apple soon.**